# Sort datastore values

Tags: sorting, gwt, datastore, objectify

I want to know the simplest way to sort the data in a datastore by descending order and retrieve the results using gwt.I have searched alot and tried many scenarios but none worked.Any help will be appreciated.
I am using objectify rather than the datastoreservice

```
static{
        ObjectifyService.register(User.class);
    }
```

So I believe they differ so is there a way to sort without Datastore service.
Here is my Query:

```
Query q = new Query("User")
            .addSort("score", SortDirection.ASCENDING);
```

I want to display the sorted values .

Answer (score 0):

If you index your entities in a datastore, you can apply a sort order when you retrieve them. Read more in the datastore documentation:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries

This issue is not related to GWT.

Alternatively, you can retrieve all entities and sort them yourself - either on the server or on the client side.

Comment: I have spent some time on reading the documentation but still can't make it work.I tried the following                                Query q = new Query("User")
            .addSort("score", SortDirection.ASCENDING);                    The Entity name is : User and I am trying to sort the scores value.Any ideas?Am I using the correct syntax??

Comment: I tried it and it sorts.But I cant sort it as integers.So when I sort it show 1,10,2,3........... instead of 1,2,3,..........,10 .Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Make sure you store data as numbers, not as strings.